# Issue in setting the timer in android

Tags: java, android, timer

I have set the timer for 2 minutes in the MainActivity.java, if i go to other activity n comeback to MainActivity the timer gets resetted. but i want the timer to be running even the Activity is changed. Please help to solve this issue. 
Here's my code for the timer.

```
//Declare the timer
    Timer t = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_timer_text);
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+String.valueOf(seconds));

                    seconds -= 1;
                    if(seconds == 0)
                    {
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+String.valueOf(seconds));

                        seconds=60;
                        minutes=minutes-1;

                  }

                }

            });
        }

    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem here?

Comment: timer should be running even if i go to the next activity  and come back... @JustinJasmann

Comment: where you are scheduling this timer? inside onCreate() or onResume()?]

Comment: inside onCreate() @GopalRao

Answer (score 0):

Use `CountDownTimer` as the calls to `onTick(long)` are synchronized

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 text.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 text.setText("done!");
             }
          }.start();
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

try this sample code...

```
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        int k = -1000;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (k == 2 * 60 * 1000) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
                Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
                return;
            }
            runOnUiThread(.... do your work....);
            k += 1000;
            Log.i(TAG, "Timer running...");
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

write this in onCreate()...